# Непонятная особенность использования `DATE (поле с DATETIME)` во вложенном запросе с HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql

***Основная информация:***

**Проблема:** решил повозиться с использованием даты во вложенном запросе в учебных для меня целях. И получаю странный результат - отдельно вложенный запрос с DATE (поле с DATETIME) работает, как нужно. Но в качестве вложенного запроса выдает ошибку. Выглядит она непонятно для меня. При этом, если в этом вложенном запросе использовать просто поле с DATETIME, то ошибки нет. Почитал документацию по DATE - все равно непонятно. *Просьба подсказать, в чем дело, как с этим справляться и есть ли аналогичные проблемы на более широком уровне? Запускаю на платформе Stepic, может у них проблема?*

**Что код делает:** если User c конкретной card в один день звонит из разных городов, то все эти звонки запрос и выдает (по всем таким User).

**Код с ошибкой:**

```
SELECT id, User, card, DATE(calling_Time) AS Calling_DATE, City 
FROM calls
WHERE (User, card, DATE(calling_Time)) IN ((
    SELECT User, card, DATE(calling_Time)  
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY User, card, DATE(calling_Time)
    HAVING COUNT(City) > 1));
```

**Текст ошибки:**
ERROR 1055: Expression #1 of HAVING clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'calls.calling_Time' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

***Дополнительная информация***

**Работающий внутренний запрос + результат:**

```
SELECT User, card, DATE(calling_Time)  
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY User, card, DATE(calling_Time)
    HAVING COUNT(City) > 1;

+------+------+--------------------+
| User | card | DATE(calling_Time) |
+------+------+--------------------+
| 1    | 1    | 2018-05-25         |
+------+------+--------------------+
Affected rows: 1
```

Работающий полный код (только без DATE) + результат:

```
SELECT id, User, card, calling_Time, City 
FROM calls
WHERE (User, card, calling_Time) IN ((SELECT User, card, calling_Time  
    FROM calls
    GROUP BY User, card, calling_Time
    HAVING COUNT(City) > 1));

+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
| id | User | card | calling_Time        | City   |
+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 1  | 1    | 1    | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 | Москва |
| 4  | 1    | 1    | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 | Питер  |
+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
Affected rows: 2
```

**Создание и заполнение тестовой таблицы:**

```
CREATE TABLE calls(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user VARCHAR (25),
    card INT,
    calling_Time DATETIME,
    City VARCHAR (25)
);
INSERT INTO calls (user, card, calling_Time, City)
    VALUES
    (1, 1, '2018-05-25 21:25:54', 'Москва'),
    (2, 1, '2018-05-25 21:25:54', 'Самара'),
    (1, 1, '2018-05-26 21:25:54', 'Москва'),
    (1, 1, '2018-05-25 21:25:54', 'Питер')
;
SELECT * FROM calls;

+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
| id | user | card | calling_Time        | City   |
+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
| 1  | 1    | 1    | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 | Москва |
| 2  | 2    | 1    | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 | Самара |
| 3  | 1    | 1    | 2018-05-26 21:25:54 | Москва |
| 4  | 1    | 1    | 2018-05-25 21:25:54 | Питер  |
+----+------+------+---------------------+--------+
Affected rows: 4
```

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, то проблема на самом деле в `City`, но объяснить почему не могу. Но не факт, что я прав.

Comment: Сергей, запустил ваш код, всё работает без ошибок. Думаю что проблема в конечной фразе - "this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by", если это так, то посмотрите решение тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by

Comment: @AndrewNikolaev, спасибо. Значит, это платформа так работает. only_full_group_by я там не отключу методами указанными, это настройки их платформы, но мне достаточно знать, что код правильный. На Oracle он работает, как вижу из сообщения ниже.

Comment: @CrazyElf, судя по ответу AndrewNikolaev,у которого мой код работает, это особенность платформы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по ответу @AndrewNikolaev, у которого мой код с потенциальной ошибкой работает, проблема с моим кодом - особенность платформы, на которой я его запускал. У автора вопроса, которому я помогал, код на Oracle тоже заработал с минимальными изменениями, вызванными разным синтаксисом версий.
Отключение only_full_group_by по совету @AndrewNikolaev должно было помочь, но на платформе Stepic я это сделать не могу.

Выводы:

1. идея была верной разместить после полноценного поиска ошибки структурированный вопрос с минимально воспроизводимым примером тут.
2. После набора опыта имеет смысл меньше времени тратить на проверки в случае подозрений на систему, если поведение явно нелогично.
3. И имеет смысл работать на своей системе, а не на внешней.